# How to crop when rotate bitmap without getting background as black in android

Tags: android, bitmap, crop, image-rotation

i want to crop bitmap when rotating the bitmap using seekbar if the rotation angle is 0,90,180,270 or 360 when apply cropping working fine like shown below.

[image]

but other angles like 20,45,130..etc when apply cropping getting background as black like shown below

[image]

i googled a lot but i'm failed for the solution.

how to crop the without background black or how to apply zoom to the view?
is have any idea or sample please tell me..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: at this angle, i suggest you to zoom the image, and then crop it

Comment: thanks for reply.. i tried to zoom but when i'm tried zoom the image automatically crop frame also extending with image. do u have any snippet or sample for this?

Comment: i am also facing the same problem @fahim

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. You've described the problem your facing, but not what the desired result would be.

Comment: Sorry @MH for Late.. how to avoid background black or how to apply the zoom for the view without exceeding crop frame..

Comment: @user512: It sounds to me like you're attempting to solve the problem of rotating a square inside the bounds of another square. Since this is a problem more related to math than programming, you'll be able to find a solution at math.stackexchange.com. For example, have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828878/calculate-dimensions-of-square-inside-a-rotated-square) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095827/scaling-and-rotating-a-square-so-that-it-is-inscribed-in-the-original-square).